# How to turn List of Objects in Map

Tags: java

I am trying to find out how to convert a list of objects to a map in java or process the list

Example
Invoice has two fields, note and amount:

```
List<Invoice> invoices = Arrays.asList(
new Invoice( "note1", "amount1" ), 
new Invoice( "note2", "amount2" ) );
```

Now can I get get this list into a Map like the following:

```
Map<Long, String>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like the following:

```
Map<Long, String> map = new HashMap<Long, String>();
for(Invoice invoice : invoces) {
    map.put(invoice.getId(), invoce.getName());
}
```

Since you did not mentioned what specifically do you want to store as `Long` key and `String` value I supposed that your class `Invoice` has long ID and String name. Yo can change the line  `map.put(...)` according to your real needs.

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static Map<Long, String> invoicesToMap(List<Invoice> invoices) {
  Map<Long, String> map = new HashMap<Long, String>();
  for (Invoice invoice : invoices) {
    map.put(Long.valueOf(invoice.getAmount()), invoice.getNote());
  }
  return map;
}
```

Comment: Even if its a sample, I won't recommend to use an "amount" property as key in a Map.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: OP asked how he can convert a list of attributed elements into a map keyed by one of the attributes (the amount); I just demonstrated how it could be done, not whether or not he should do it.

Comment: I'm not referring to the whole example (that shows what OP needs). I mean that even in a sample, I won't say "you could use the long value of an amount as key", just that :).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: oh yes, I see.  Agreed =)